# Problem reading from file

Tags: java, file-io

so i'm trying to read from a file a number of lines, and after that put them in a String[]. but it doesn't seem to work. what have i done wrong?

```
     String[] liniiFisier=new String[20];
    int i=0;
    try{
          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          String strLine;
          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              liniiFisier[i]=strLine;
              i++;
          }
          //Close the input stream
          in.close();
            }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
                System.out.println(liniiFisier[i]);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: it reads correctly the number of lines...but the text is not saved

Comment: As a side note, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the file has more than 20 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change that last line to

```
System.out.println(liniiFisier[j]);  // important: use j, not i
```

Answer (score 1):

You should tell us what's happening and what problem occurred.

But I yet see some errors:

1. Imagine your file has more than 20 lines, so you'll try to access `liniiFisier[20]`, but this field is not present! Results in `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`
2. In your `for` loop you are iterating `j` but always using `i`...
3. Creating the `BufferedReader` can be done in less code:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader ("textfile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
```

Since I don't know about your particular problem this might not solve it, so please provide more information ;-)